# using class module properties in UDF's excel vba

Tags: class, excel, vba

I have the following function that works fine:

```
Function GetAgentEmailWorksheet(AgentObjectId As String)
    Dim specific_agent As clsAgent
    Set specific_agent = New clsAgent

    specific_agent.AgentSheetName = "agentsFullOutput.csv"

    Dim id_array() As Variant
    id_array = specific_agent.AgentIDArray

    Dim email_array() As Variant
    email_array = specific_agent.AgentEmailArray

    GetAgentEmailWorksheet = vlook_using_array(AgentObjectId, id_array, email_array)

End Function
```

When, however, I change the last line to:

```
GetAgentEmailWorksheet = vlook_using_array(AgentObjectId, specific_agent.AgentIDArray, specific_agent.AgentEmailArray)
```

I get the following error:

```
Compile error:
Type mismatch:array or user-defined type expected
```

and it hi-lights `AgentIDArray` (or `AgentEmailArray` if I sub out the first parameter.

Why?

**EDIT**

here's the fuction `vlook_using_array`:

```
Function vlook_using_array(target_string As String, _
                    input_array() As Variant, _
                    output_array() As Variant)

    Dim rows_dim As Long
    Dim cols_dim As Integer

    For rows_dim = 1 To UBound(input_array, 1)
        For cols_dim = 1 To UBound(input_array, 2)
            If input_array(rows_dim, cols_dim) = target_string Then
                vlook_using_array = output_array(rows_dim, cols_dim)
            End If
        Next cols_dim
    Next rows_dim

End Function
```

Here are the clsAgent properties:

```
Public Property Get AgentClientsArray() As Variant
    AgentClientsArray = get_column_array(AgentClientsCol)
End Property

Public Property Get AgentIDArray() As Variant
    AgentIDArray = get_column_array(1)
End Property

Public Property Get AgentEmailArray() As Variant
    AgentEmailArray = get_column_array(AgentEmailCol)
End Property
```

Here's the function that's in the class module:

```
Private Function get_column_array(col_num As Integer) As Variant
'   create a range out of the used range (of the sheet) in the column specified
'   used to create array properties in the class

    Dim total_rows As Long
    total_rows = Worksheets(Me.AgentSheetName).UsedRange.rows.Count

    Dim target_range As Range
    With Worksheets(Me.AgentSheetName)
        Set target_range = .Range(.Cells(1, col_num), .Cells(total_rows, col_num))
    End With

    Dim target_arr() As Variant
    target_arr = target_range

    get_column_array = target_arr

 End Function
```

Comment: What parameter types does `vlook_using_array` expect?

Comment: I added the function.  the parameters expect arrays, I hope.

Comment: In your class, what are the return types of `AgentIDArray` and `AgentEmailArray` ?

Comment: I added the properties to the question.

Comment: I still don't see the property for AgentEmailArray.  Can you `debug.print TypeName(email_array) & vbLf &  TypeName(specific_agent.AgentEmailArray` right after `email_array = specific_agent.AgentEmailArray` .  Maybe do the same for id_array to be thorough?

Comment: I rant the debug as written and got `V()
V()
`

Answer (score 0):

There's a difference between this:

```
Public Property Get AgentIDArray() As Variant
    AgentIDArray = get_column_array(1)
End Property
```

and

```
Public Property Get AgentIDArray() As Variant()
    AgentIDArray = get_column_array(1)
End Property
```

The first (which you have in your class) returns a Variant which happens to be an array, the second an *array of variants*.

So, the return value of your `AgentIDArray` is not consistent with the parameter types expected by `vlook_using_array`